# SwiftUI Memory Leak With Forms and Lists

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swiftui

I am developing simple to-do app with `SwiftUI`. During my tests i noticed my view models never calls deinit and causing linear increase in memory usage.

**I reproduced the same behavior with following code:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("open") {
            self.isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ViewModel

    init() {
        model = ViewModel()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Toggle Me", isOn: $model.isOn)
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn = false

    deinit {
        print("ViewModel deinit ")
    }
}
```

When sheet is dismissed, model object never deinits. If i replace the form with VStack or ScrollView then model is deinited. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bug. Only workaround that worked for me is using ScrollView. Then again, ScrollView comes with its own animation bugs.

EDIT

Issue seems to have been resolved in iOS 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You're understanding `deinit()` wrong. When you're dismissing a `View` it doesn't necessarily mean it's going to call `deinit()` like you think. If your `ViewModel` was destroyed however it would call `deinit()` as you expect.

To demonstrate this, here’s a `Person` class with a name property, a simple initializer, and a `printGreeting()` method that prints a message:

```
class Person {
    var name = "John Doe"

    init() {
        print("\(name) is alive!")
    }

    func printGreeting() {
        print("Hello, I'm \(name)")
    }
}
```

We’re going to create a few instances of the `Person` class inside a loop, because each time the loop goes around a new person will be created then destroyed:

```
for _ in 1...3 {
    let person = Person()
    person.printGreeting()
}
```

And now for the deinitializer. This will be called when the `Person` instance is being **destroyed**:

```
deinit {
    print("\(name) is no more!")
}
```

Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/8/6/deinitializers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how deinit() works. 

Problem here is ViewModel should destroy after dismiss. Because it does when Form is replaced with VStack. In current state if i reopen sheet 100 times, 100 instances of ViewModel created and never released.

Comment: ViewModel is initialized in SheetView and when SheetView is dismissed there should be no references to ViewModel anymore. But looks like there are and that's a kind of unexpected. I experience the same when switching tabs for example.